# JavaScript "onClick" event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this line in my PHP file:

```
echo "<input type='button' id='showButton' value='show'  onclick='showOld()'>";
```

The button is displayed but when it is clicked, nothing happens.

The function is located in an external JS file.
this is function declaration:

Other `onclick` events and JS functions in the page are working.

```
function showOld()
{
alert("njkh");
var table = document.getElementById("showExp");
var button = document.getElementById("showButton");
if (table.style.display == "none")
{
    table.style.display = "inline";
    button.value = "הסתר ניסויים ישנים";
}
else if (table.style.display == "inline")
{
    table.style.display = "none";
    button.value = "הצג את כל הניסויים";
}       
}
```

**console says:**

> "ReferenceError: showOld is not defined"

Comment: Maybe some of the Javascript is wrong. I can't see anything wrong in the HTML. Please post the JS code as well. Or make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: Edit the question to add your JavaScript code for the function `showOld()`.

Comment: Where is the external JS file included? It should be included before the input button so that the function is available. Also check your spelling. If you have Firefox with Firebug, open the console and refresh to see if any exceptions show up.

Comment: @TJ - this is not correct.  showOld() will not be called or referenced until clicked (because it's passed as a string that won't be evaluated until the click) so it does not have to be before the input button.

Comment: problem solved when i moved declaration from the bottom to different location inside the JS file (???). nevertheless on IE i still get "Object Error" message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must make sure your updated code had been deployed.

you can check the html source .

and your posted code has no any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening up firebug's console (or chrome dev tools) and check for any script errors.

You should avoid writing inline javascript. It makes it harder to debug and maintain your codebase. I recommend that you read the following articles on javascript events:

[Quirksmode - Early Event Handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)

[Quirksmode - Traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

A quote from the article:

> Although the inline event registration model is ancient and reliable,
>   it has one serious drawback. It requires you to write JavaScript
>   behavior code in your XHTML structure layer, where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1):

First, simplify the problem, see if the following function works.

```
function showOld() {
alert('test');
}
```

Comment: i tried.. still not working. console says "showOld is not defined"

Comment: Try to define this function inside '<body>' tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try next to check for exceptions:

```
<input type='button' id='showButton' value='show' onclick='javascript:alert(1);try{showOld()}catch(e){alert(e)}' />
```

And what exactly is displayed in the javascript console (if available)?

Comment: hi. alert() is working, console says "showOld" is not defined.

Comment: @itamar If console says "showOld is not defined" and showOld is defined and loaded into browser: then showOld is hidden by closure, for example: _function() { function showOld(){} }_. Update your post and add showOld function declaration code.

Comment: problem solved when i moved declaration from the bottom to different location inside the JS file.. (???)

Comment: @itamar As shown in your showOld code, your .js-file contains Hebrew letters. How your .js-files is encoded (with UTF8 or unicode or any other?). When you load .js files with SCRIPT do you properly specify _charset_ attribute?

Comment: thank you for your help. the charset attribute was specified. now its working well on firefox but on IE i get "object error" message.

Comment: Open IE developers tool window (IE8+). Press "Start debugging" button  and check: what a line throws an error "object error" in the console.